# Only fade in on a given scroll position && if display is 'none'

Tags: jquery

I am building a single page scroll site with a menu which scrolls to the content sections on click and then fades in the relevant area.

This works nicely.

On top of that I am fading in the sections if the user just scrolls, without the click event.

All the divisions to be faded in have display set to 'none'.

Both above methods work on their own, however there are issues when the event cross eachother,i.e:

If i add the fadeIn code to the scroll function, the following happens:

At the very beginning, you have to scroll a bit to fade in the content, because if i do not, the click even on the menu items will not fire.

And if i click the menu item "about us" for example, it scrolls to the targeted section of the page and fades in the content, this is good, but after this, the on scroll function fires again and fades the same content in again.

In summary, i am trying to make the content only fade in if display is set to hidden and the scroll position is right.

And of course, the section should scroll and fade in from the very default position, when the target sections are still set to display 'none'.

I have tried conditional statements, using visibilty:hidden and many other things, but i can't get it too work.

```
 <div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="button" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="button"  href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a  class="button" href="#service">Services</a></li>
<li><a  class="button" href="faqs.html">Galleries</a</li>
<li><a  class="button" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

$(window).scroll(function() { 
if ($(this).scrollTop()> 100) { 
$('.about').fadeIn(2000); 
} else { 
$('.about').fadeOut(); 
} 
});

$(".button").on("click", function( e ) {
$('.rightcservices').fadeIn(2000);
e.preventDefault();

$("body, html").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
}, 600);
});
});
```

The goal is to have the links fade in on scroll or click, default setting for the sections set to display none.

Comment: Could you add the code (and maybe a live link)?

Comment: If you'd adapt this pen so it matches the live environment more I'm sure it could be solved without too much effort. The relationship between  HTML and script isn't very clear yet. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKKbPN

Comment: @Shikkediel
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/wKKbjO

Comment: @Shikkediel


I have added nonsense text and a random pic everywhere and only posted the relevant jquery bits for ease of use, sorry for the big css file:-)  
As this is not the whole page, the scroll on click will only work on the "about" and "services" links(removed the relevant triggers).but that is good enough.
The jq code is just for the about content to fade out on scroll, the goal is to make sections fade in on both hand/mouse scroll and on a click triggered scroll, whatever i have the fade in will trigger twice or not at all.Thank you

Comment: Cheers, no problem. I'll have a good look at it.

Comment: @Shikkediel
Thank you, i just wanted to mention that there i a hack around the issue, by setting the click-scroll targets just outside the content to be faded out, but that is hardly a satisfying solution.There must be some way to make this work with a conditional statement:-)

Comment: I still seem to be having some trouble understanding the desired effect but reading the descriptions I could maybe offer a few tools. Using `display: none` will take the item out of document flow so anchor clicking won't work. Instead you could use `opacity: 0` and `fadeTo(400, 1)`. To add a check inside the `if` statement for visibility, something like `if ($('#anchor').is(':visible')) // do something` could do the trick. Hope that helps so far. I'll read through another time.

Comment: Nono, this works with click events on anchors on display none, but i want JQ to check if the element is visible or not, on manual scroll and on click scroll. And then to fade in the content only is it is not visible.I added a change to the script, you will see that if you click on the "about" link, the about content fades in, but then it faded in again, fired by the scrolltop function.I hope this helps.

Comment: I see what you mean now, that's animation queue buildup. You can prevent it by using this in your scroll function : `$('.about').stop().fadeIn(2000);.` To check if an element has an animation in progress something like `if ($('.about').is(':animated'))` can come in handy. But to be honest, I don't get why a second fade inside the click function would be necessary. The scroll function will 'respond' to both manual scrolling and the scroll position that is set by the animation...

Comment: @Shikkediel, thanks, now we are getting closer, i actually want to prevent that second fadeIn, it is undesired.I only want the content to be faded in once, on manual scroll or click.
Its not even so much for the visual effect, its to "mask" my sequential loading of the images:-) I hope now it's clear, sorry for this being hard to explain with words:-)

Comment: I was wondering - didn't the about section look as you actually intend before the latest addition of that `fadeIn`? It would work on both click and scroll. I think I get it now (it's not you by the way, it just difficult to convey) - each section should scroll (manually or animated) to the anchor with a certain id and then the following div with a class matching that id should fade in. If I'm am correct, let me know. I'll see if I can come up with some slick optimised code.

Comment: @Shikkediel
Yes! That would be the idea, now we are getting there. I works if i put the id of scroll target say into the h2, or a list item and only fadein/out the content of the section, but that is not a perfect solution.If the Id target(the one to scroll to) is within the faded out section, then the click event for scrolling will never fire:-)This can be avoided by having the id scroll target outside the fadein area(just fading in/out everything under the nav).That's right i put the last bit of fade in code in there just for you to see the issue.:-)

Comment: Have a look at comment number seven, the only way to hide an element but have it in document flow would be to give it zero opacity. I could implement that if you like (putting some code together already). The `fadeOut()` method adds `display: none` at the end of the animation (then the page has nowhere to scroll to) while `fadeTo` only sets opacity (element is still there but not visible). But I don't think it's such a bad idea or even a compromise to just fade in the content and have the actual element that is the anchor be visible at all times.

Comment: @Shikkediel , yes i would appreciate that, check the js code, i have played around with it a bit, i think as it is now, we would only the to add an && operator to the if statement, something like "if ($(window).scrollTop()> 100) && ($('.about').css('display') == 'none') {}, but this gives an error.
I would be happy with the solution changing opacity too, it is not important whether the element are not visible or set to display none.

Comment: I see you've been working on it @damiano celent but it may be worth having a look at this (could be a work in progress if you like). http://tinyurl.com/nslsyjp

Comment: @Shikkediel
Thank you so much, that is actually perfect, i have added couple more id anchors and it work flawlessly, i would give you 1000 rep points for this and your patience:-)
Can you explain the var nadir and the target = $('.' + this) part?
And just to be sure, the element var contains the strings from the nav, not the id's, right?
This is amazing:-)

Comment: So I think I ended up making it like they you originally intended anyway, manual scrolling and anchor clicking are triggering separate fades now. Looks like all you'd need to tweak are the fading durations and the values for `zenith` and `nadir` to influence when they will be shown on manual scroll exactly. I won't post any comments below this anymore (must be a record). If there's something I overlooked, let me know in the section below the answer. Should be working pretty slick now though. B-)

Answer (score 1):

After all the comments let me post the final code with some clarification. Went overboard a bit (that happens sometimes with interesting functionality here), initially thinking is couldn't be too complicated to fix. But I underestimated that somewhat and ended up separating manual scroll from animation by adding a variable `pilot` and using that as a switch and blocking mechanism for the onscroll listener function to execute fading whenever there's manual scrolling. Also put the second instance of fading in the callback of the animation, together with flipping the switch back.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvrvNP?editors=001

```
$(function() {

    var anchors = ['home','about','services','contact'],
    target, zenith, nadir, location, pilot,
    modern = window.requestAnimationFrame;

    storeDimensions();

    $(window).resize(storeDimensions).scroll(function() {

        location = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (!pilot) {
        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(checkFade);
        else checkFade();
        }
    });

    $('.button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        pilot = true;

        var destination = $(this.hash).offset().top,
        goal = $('.' + this.hash.substr(1));

        if (destination != location) goal.hide();

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: destination}, 600, function() {

            goal.fadeIn(2000);
            pilot = false;
        });
    });

function storeDimensions() {

    var placement = []; target = []; zenith = []; nadir = [];

    $.each(anchors, function(n) {

        placement.push($('#' + this).offset().top);
        target.push($('.' + this));
        zenith.push(placement[n]-$(window).height()*0.8);
        nadir.push(placement[n]+target[n].outerHeight(true));
    });
}

function checkFade() {

    $.each(anchors, function(i) {

        if (!target[i].is(':animated')) {
        if (location > zenith[i] && location < nadir[i]) target[i].fadeIn(2000);
        else if (target[i].is(':visible')) target[i].hide();
        }
    });
}
});
```

I have noticed a quirk when using `fadeOut()` instead of `hide()` and will see if that can be fixed. Script should be functioning well as is but any possible future updates can be found in this demo :

http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/avdyWx?editors=001

---

Here's an earlier version and comments from before realising that precalculating and storing all the dimensions and offsets is actually a lot more efficient than getting the values on each scroll update. I'll leave the text there as well because it might make the basic idea clearer :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOOeod?editors=001

The array `elements` indeed contains the names of the anchors, we will start cycling through them on scroll here : `$.each(elements, function() {`. That way there's no need to write a conditional statement for them separately.

For the variables `object` and `target` inside the loop, `this` will in turn be each of the anchor names in the array. So they will end up as a jQuery selector representing the element to scroll to, for example `$('#about')`, and the element with the matching class that should be faded in - `$('.about')`.

The variables `zenith` and `nadir` are the page's highest and lowest scroll positions in between which each of the anchored sections will be shown. When using `object.offset().top` the element would start to fade in when it is at the top. Subtracting window height, it will start the fade when it reaches the *bottom* of the screen (seemed like a nicer detail). The lowest scroll position to be used (`nadir`, changed that one a bit since the comments) represents the position of the anchor itself plus the height of the fading content, padding and margin included. So if the visible subject goes off the screen (approximately in the live example) by scrolling up, it will be hidden again.

I've also added an optimisation for the scroll function. Especially on Firefox with smoothscroll enabled it can fire a lot so the CPU is given an easier time by only recalculating whenever a repaint of the screen is due using `requestAnimationFrame`. And a fallback to 'normal' behaviour when the feature isn't available. When a button is clicked and a scroll animation starts, jQuery will fire about a hundred times a second so this is a good thing to do for any device.